# Magento 2 : PayPal express checkout is redirecting to cart page, without showing any success or failure error

Tags: magento2, checkout, paypal-express

I am using PayPal express checkout on my Magento 2.2.6 website.
Steps to reproduce the issue that is

> 1. Add product to cart
> 2. From the cart page click Paypal express checkout button
> 3. Add the details on PayPal
> 4. On the PayPal review page, apply the discount coupon and it will redirect to the cart page
> 5. Click on the express checkout button again, add the details on PayPal again
> 6. and now instead of redirecting to the PayPal review page, I am redirecting to the cart page.

Can anyone suggest to me how to debug this issue in more detail?

Contents of the payment.log file are

```
  'url' => 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp',
  'GetExpressCheckoutDetails' => 
  array (
    'TOKEN' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'METHOD' => 'GetExpressCheckoutDetails',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'USER' => '****',
    'PWD' => '****',
    'SIGNATURE' => '****',
    'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_Cart_Community',
  ),
  'response' => 
  array (
    'TOKEN' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS' => '0',
    'CHECKOUTSTATUS' => 'PaymentActionNotInitiated',
    'TIMESTAMP' => '2019-12-05T09:56:40Z',
    'CORRELATIONID' => xxxxxxxxxxx
    'ACK' => 'Success',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'BUILD' => '53842365',
    'EMAIL' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'PAYERID' => '76QH8A6BV9GWC',
    'PAYERSTATUS' => 'unverified',
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'Naveed',
    'LASTNAME' => 'Abbas',
    'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
    'SHIPTONAME' => 'Naveed Abbas',
    'SHIPTOSTREET' => 'street 123',
    'SHIPTOCITY' => 'huntsville',
    'SHIPTOSTATE' => 'AL',
    'SHIPTOZIP' => '35801',
    'SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
    'SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME' => 'United States',
    'BILLINGNAME' => 'Naveed Abbas',
    'STREET' => 'street 123',
    'CITY' => 'huntsville',
    'STATE' => 'AL',
    'ZIP' => '35801',
    'COUNTRY' => 'US',
    'COUNTRYNAME' => 'United States',
    'ADDRESSID' => 'PayPal',
    'ADDRESSSTATUS' => 'Confirmed',
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
    'AMT' => '67.97',
    'ITEMAMT' => '67.97',
    'SHIPPINGAMT' => '0.00',
    'HANDLINGAMT' => '0.00',
    'TAXAMT' => '0.00',
    'INVNUM' => '600313',
    'INSURANCEAMT' => '0.00',
    'SHIPDISCAMT' => '0.00',
    'INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED' => 'false',
    'L_NAME0' => 'Newspaper Holder in Met. Bronze for Gaines Mailbox',
    'L_QTY0' => '1',
    'L_TAXAMT0' => '0.00',
    'L_AMT0' => '67.97',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => '67.97',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => '67.97',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT' => '0.00',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT' => '0.00',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT' => '0.00',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM' => '600313',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT' => '0.00',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT' => '0.00',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED' => 'false',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME' => 'Naveed Abbas',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET' => 'street 123',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY' => 'huntsville',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE' => 'AL',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP' => '35801',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME' => 'United States',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS' => 'Confirmed',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => 'Newspaper Holder in Met. Bronze for Gaines Mailbox',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0' => '1',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0' => '0.00',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => '67.97',
    'PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE' => '0',
  ),
) [] []
[2019-12-05 09:56:44] main.DEBUG: array (
  'url' => 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp',
  'getPalDetails' => 
  array (
    'METHOD' => 'getPalDetails',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'USER' => '****',
    'PWD' => '****',
    'SIGNATURE' => '****',
    'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_Cart_Community',
  ),
  'response' => 
  array (
    'PAL' => 'RGZTJUM7RDV9C',
    'LOCALE' => 'en_US',
    'TIMESTAMP' => '2019-12-05T09:56:43Z',
    'CORRELATIONID' => 'd3619b72ea406',
    'ACK' => 'Success',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'BUILD' => '53802284',
  ),
) [] []
```

in file 
`vendor/magento/module-paypal/Controller/Express/AbstractExpress/ReturnAction.php`
there is a condition

````
if ($this->_checkout->canSkipOrderReviewStep()) {
    $this->_forward('placeOrder');
} else {
    $this->_redirect('*/*/review');
}
return;```
in 2nd attempt it goes into else part, but without redirecting, control shipts outside of the if, else block and the cart page remains there.
````

Comment: have you enable debug mode from backend payment method configuration ?

Comment: Yes debug mode is enabled

Comment: so any payment.log file in log folder ?if yes then please share that logs

Comment: Edited the question and added the payment.log contents. Tokens and emails etc are converted to xxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: I have done some debugging and found that the PayPal API is stuck after GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and it is not calling getPalDetails. Now trying to find out why it is happening.

Comment: Okay so issue is that

Comment: Yes that is the issue, but don't know why this is happening for some cases.

Comment: @PradipGarchar I have added my findings in the question. can you please check that?

Comment: yes its check just if condition in SkipOrderReviewStep , if yes then just placed order without review page   and here i think its goes to else part review page

Comment: Yes, but it stays on the cart page and not redirecting to the review page. but if I access the review page it loads it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please Set **Yes** into **"Transfer Cart Line Items"** from PayPal advanced settings, see the below image for your reference.

Hope it helps you !

[image]

Comment: These settings are alread applied. The issue occurs when we move to cart page from review page and click on PayPal express checkout button again.

Comment: did you add extra cost or fee to cart?

Comment: No extra cost, and this issue mainly occur in case if you apply a coupon code with 100% discount and then remove it.

Comment: @Dhrumin For my case Transfer Cart Line Items "Yes"  still redirect to the cart page instead of the Paypal payment page.  Any help thanks.

Comment: @zus , did customized anything into paypal , check your custom modules, otherwise default functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Shipping Address was incorrect, It only showed the error when I set **"Enable In-Context Checkout Experience"** to **"Yes"**